# Foreign Key constraint on Postgres necessary with GUI?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a GUI program with a Postgres database. In the database, I have a customer table like this:

```
id serial Primary Key | name
----------------------+------
21                    | Mr. Customer
```

I also have an invoices table like this (simplified):

```
id | customer_id
---+------
4  | 21
```

I am not using Foreign Keys as my GUI does not allow anyone to insert a wrong number for the customer_id. However, my friend is telling me I am stupid to not use Foreign Keys. Can somebody point out a possible scenario where a wrong value could be inserted into the customer_id column? I will change my database for one good reason, but so far I have not thought of a reason.

Comment: Your friend is correct.   You are asserting that nobody, ever, can access the database other than from your GUI?

Comment: Foreign keys help enforce [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity in relational databases. The database should be responsible for enforcing it in most scenarios, not your application.

Comment: @OldProgrammer No, it would be possible to edit a table with PGadmin or other. I figured in that case, the user would know that the customer_id is from another table. So you gave me at least one instance that a FK would be in order. Thanks.

Comment: Show me an application that claims it can deal with all constraints in the application logic and I will show you a database that has invalid/inconsistent data in it - at least after a couple of months. I have **never** seen this working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reasons,

**Inserting data from other sources.**
As @OldProgrammer pointed out, someone can insert data into the table using pgadmin or psql client.

**Deleting customers**
What happens when a customer is deleted in the customer table. You have an entry in the invoices table where a customer doesn't exists.

**Updating customers**
As above

**Extra queries**
In order to manually inforce a foreign key in your app, you need to do a select from the customer table to find out if a user by exists. Then only can you perform the insert. So you are doing an extra query, not to mention writing a whole lot of extra code to replace something that's already built into the database.

**Programming errors**
Your GUI might well contain a bug that causes invalid data to be entered. A constraint in the database will keep you safe in this case. This technique is called *defensive programming* and adds quality to your system for little cost.

Comment: About *Extra Queries* : all the customers and ids are populated into a combobox. I do not need to look up the id, I already have it when a customer is selected. About *Deleting Customers* : in my case, no customers are permanently deleted they are set as deleted and remain in the system, albeit invisible. However, you bring something to my attention. A user could use PGadmin and delete a customer. An FK would eliminate this possibility.

Comment: I have 1000 customers in a combobox. The combo also has a text entry to search. How many customers does it take to become unwieldy?

Comment: OK I am not trying to find fault, but if you have a 1000 customers, you could still have 999 possible wrong entries. So the FK would enforce that you cannot enter a integer value *outside* the 1000 customers. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: that is indeed so. You can associate customer_id1 where what's required is customer_id2 foreign keys will allow you to do that.

Comment: You mentioned updating a table as a reason for using FK. I am linking my tables *only* by id (which is a serial PK). And to my knowledge a serial PK cannot be changed (easily). How would a FK help in that case? Just to clarify: if I have a customer_id of 4 in the invoices table and I need to know the customer name, I SELECT it from the customer table. Again I am not arguing, I am trying to understand why we do things this way.

Comment: I don't understand the latest comment.

Comment: Quote from your answer: Updating customers As above. If an invoice is for customer_id1 and I update that customer name in the customer table the id will not change. The customer name is not stored in the invoice table (only the id). How will a FK be of value in this case?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, the FK ensures that the ID you are entering is an id that exists in the referenced table. There is no way that any program can know whether you intended to insert the id for customer one or customer 2. The only way that any program can know that is if you write the code for it yourself. But that sort of code is darned hard to write.

Comment: All the best with your project.